# How can I parse an outlook table using vba, to automatically update quickparts?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have tried to find an answer to my question without any success, so apologies if it has been asked before.

I have an outlook message table containing a table, that I want to parse using vba to create or update quick part entries.

The table looks something like this :

```
+-----+--------------+--------------+
| xxx |       A      |       B      |
+-----+--------------+--------------+
|  1  |   sampleA1   |   sampleB1   |
+-----+--------------+--------------+
|  2  |   sampleA2   |   sampleB2   |
+-----+--------------+--------------+
|  3  |   sampleA3   |   sampleB3   |
+-----+--------------+--------------+
```

My objective is to generate quick parts whose ID will be for example "xxxA1" and the corresponding text "sampleA1".

The ID will be constructed from the first cell of the table and the row and column headers, and the values will be the corresponding cell contents.

I hope this is clear.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Chris

Comment: so you are trying to collect data from your email put on spreadsheet?

Comment: No, I want to read the table and store it as quick part entries within Outlook. My difficulty is in accessing the table and it's cells. I have read the "Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies" article, which gives some clues, but I don't know anything about the Word DOM, all my VBA experience is with Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've managed to read the table, but I now can't find how to access Quickparts to store what I've just read.

My code so far looks like this.

```
Sub ParseTable2QuickParts()
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objDoc As Object 'Word.Document
    Dim objSel As Object 'Word.Selection

    Dim cTitle As String
    Dim acRow(10) As String
    Dim nRow As Integer
    Dim acCol(10) As String
    Dim nCol As Integer
    Dim acValues(10, 10) As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objOL = Application
    If objOL.ActiveInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
        Set objDoc = objOL.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
        Set objNS = objOL.Session

        Set objSel = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection

        objSel.Move wdstory, -1
        objSel.Move wdTable, 1
        objSel.Expand 12
        cTitle = Left(objSel.Text, Len(objSel.Text) - 2)

        For nCol = 2 To 3
           objSel.Move wdRow, 0
           objSel.Move wdCell, 1
           objSel.Expand 12
           acCol(nCol) = Left(objSel.Text, Len(objSel.Text) - 2)
        Next

        For nRow = 2 To 4
           objSel.Move wdRow, 1
           objSel.Move wdCell, 0
           objSel.Expand 12
           acRow(nRow) = Left(objSel.Text, Len(objSel.Text) - 2)
        Next

        objSel.Move wdstory, -1
        objSel.Move wdTable, 1
        For nRow = 2 To 4
            objSel.Move wdRow, 1
            For nCol = 2 To 3
                objSel.Move wdCell, 1
                objSel.Expand 12
                acValues(nCol, nRow) = Left(objSel.Text, Len(objSel.Text) - 2)
            Next
        Next

        objSel.Move wdstory, 1
        For nRow = 2 To 4
            For nCol = 2 To 3
                objSel.InsertAfter cTitle & acCol(nCol) & acRow(nRow) & " => " & acValues(nCol, nRow) & vbCrLf
            Next
        Next

    End If
    Set objOL = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing

End Sub
```

I just need to replace the final nested loops to store what I've read rather than just dump  it back to the message. Can anyone point me in the right direction ?